# Editing Feature Class using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, c#, feature-class

I have a problem with editing feature class using ArcObjects.  Indeed I am working on it for a while and can't find any solution into doing it... I asked a question before about how to connect to database and I thought the problem is with it but I find another problem... Here is my code:

```
// getLayerFromGeoDatabase();
// Create the workspace factory.
        Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
        IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory2 = workspaceFactory as IWorkspaceFactory2;
        // Build a connection string.
        String[] connectionProps = 
{
    "dbclient=SQLServer", "serverinstance=CRAZYVIRUS-HP", 
        "database=test", "authentication_mode=OSA" 
};
        String connString = String.Join(";", connectionProps);
        IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySetClass();
        propertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", "CRAZYVIRUS-HP");
        //propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "CRAZYVIRUS-HP");
        propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "land_gis");
        propertySet.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "OSA");
        //propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "123456");
        //propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "sde.DEFAULT");

        //IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory2.OpenFromString(propertySet, 0);
        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory2.Open(propertySet, 0);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; // Explict Cast
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("test.DBO.test");

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass();
        featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureClass;
        featureLayer.Name = featureClass.AliasName;
        featureLayer.Visible = true;

        IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)workspace;

        // Start an edit session. An undo/redo stack isn't necessary in this case.
        workspaceEdit.StartEditing(false);

        // Start an edit operation.
        workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

        // Create a row. The row's attribute values should be set here and if
        // a feature is being created, the shape should be set as well.
        IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
        feature.Store();

        // Save the edit operation. To cancel an edit operation, the AbortEditOperation
        // method can be used.
        workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();

        // Stop the edit session. The saveEdits parameter indicates the edit session
        // will be committed.
        workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

I can connect to database but can't add features in it. I got a error in this line:

```
IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
```

it says

```
enter code hereUnderlying DBMS error[[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'R7_pk'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TEST'. The duplicate key value is (0).]
```

I can connect to database using ArcCatalog and also I have enabled versioning for featureclass in ArcCatalog... I am really confused with this problem... I have already used Create Enterprise Geodatabase for this database and also my feature class is empty. Sometimes I got this error on the same line.

I think there is something wrong with code... Some how this code creates a new feature but is says this new one is duplicated:(

**Update**

I managed to make this code work:

```
Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
        IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
        IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory2 = workspaceFactory as IWorkspaceFactory2;

        IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySetClass();
        propertySet.SetProperty("dbclient", "SQLServer");
        propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "land_gis");
        propertySet.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "OSA");

        IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory2.Open(propertySet, 0);
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; // Explict Cast
        ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("test.DBO.test");

        ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer featureLayer = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.FeatureLayerClass();
        featureLayer.FeatureClass = featureClass;
        featureLayer.Name = featureClass.AliasName;
        featureLayer.Visible = true;

        IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)workspace;
        workspaceEdit.StartEditing(false);
        workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

        IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
        feature.Shape = polygon;

        ISubtypes subtypes = (ISubtypes)featureClass;
        IRowSubtypes rowSubtypes = (IRowSubtypes)feature;
        rowSubtypes.InitDefaultValues();

        int EnergyFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("Energy");
        feature.set_Value(EnergyFieldIndex, property_info[1]);

        int corp_typeFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("corp_type");
        feature.set_Value(corp_typeFieldIndex, property_info[2]);

        int PoolFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("Pool");
        feature.set_Value(PoolFieldIndex, property_info[3]);

        int irrigationFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("irrigation");
        feature.set_Value(irrigationFieldIndex, property_info[4]);

        int varietyFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("variety");
        feature.set_Value(varietyFieldIndex, property_info[5]);

        int treesFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("trees");
        feature.set_Value(treesFieldIndex, Convert.ToInt16(property_info[6]));

        int utilizatFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("utilizat");
        feature.set_Value(utilizatFieldIndex, property_info[7]);

        int addressFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("address");
        feature.set_Value(addressFieldIndex, property_info[9]);

        int water_hourFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("water_hour");
        feature.set_Value(water_hourFieldIndex, Convert.ToDecimal(property_info[10]));

        int owner_IDFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("owner_ID");
        feature.set_Value(owner_IDFieldIndex, Convert.ToInt16(property_info[11]));

        int w_sourceFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("w_source");
        feature.set_Value(w_sourceFieldIndex, property_info[12]);

        int w_incheFieldIndex = featureClass.FindField("w_inche");
        feature.set_Value(w_incheFieldIndex, Convert.ToDecimal(property_info[13]));

        feature.Store();
        workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
        workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

I set feature.Shape = polygon; using this piece of code:

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesFile.ShapefileWorkspaceFactoryClass();
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IWorkspace workspace = workspaceFactory.OpenFromFile(string_ShapefileDirectory, 0);
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace featureWorkspace = (ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)workspace; // Explict Cast
ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeatureClass featureClass = featureWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(string_ShapefileName);
Polygon p2 = featureClass.GetFeature(0).Shape as Polygon;
SelectedFeature = p2 as IPolygon;
```

I get an error that says `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to numeric`

I think the problem is with one of myfields... How can I find which one makes this problem... I know that this error says that a field in the database is attempted to insert or update larger data of the same type or other data type but can't manage to find which one it is.

Comment: Your data, test, it exists doesn't it? This sounds like more of a database problem than an object problem. Note that SDE does not allow storing a feature with an empty geometry so creating a feature and storing it without setting the geometry is going to cause problems.

Comment: Dear @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks for your answer..I solved my previous problem.But now I faced another one..Can you please take a look at my update in question?Thanks a lot

Comment: On what line does it give the error? Please don't use .Shape to read the geometry, always use .ShapeCopy, the use of .Shape may have unintended side effects. I am thinking that your Polygon should be IPolygon so Polygon p2 = featureClass.GetFeature(0).Shape as **IPolygon**; normally though it's IGeometry that is stored in the shape.

Comment: Dear @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks for your great help..I found that the problem is in Area field..I did not get you about dont using .shape..you mean '  feature.ShapeCopy=polygon;'I am not sure that this works.?

Comment: No Majid, **get** the geometry from ShapeCopy, **put** the geometry into Shape: IPolygon pPol = (IPolygon)feature.ShapeCopy; *to get* feature.Shape = (IGeometry)pPol; *to put*.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thank you so much it worked

Comment: It seems you need some 'using' statements also... Dont you find typing ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.xxxx everytime quite time consuming and annoying?

Comment: @HowdyDoody If I use workspeace and feature class to show in azmapviewer object,Can I clean workspease with using?